# How do you get multiple ports working with nginx proxy_pass and Node Express?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have multiple node instances running each on a different port. (8000, 8001, etc.) I also have nginx running on port 80. What I am trying to do is allow a user to enter my site via a single domain name, and then via different urls be able to access a different node server.

Currently everything works as following

http://example.com:8000/index.html (This is one node server running a site)
http://example.com:8001/index.hmtl (this is another node server running a different site)

What I want to be able to do is allow the user to type in a url path and auto direct them to the correct site without them having to specify the port. So for instance:

http://example.com/site1/inedx.html (This is one node server running a site at port 8000)
http://example.com/site2/index.html (this is another node server running a different site at port 8001)

I have been trying to achieve this with nginx proxy_pass rules but am having trouble getting it to work. Essentially nginx reroutes to the correct express server, but then all my routing in the express app breaks because it lacks the port.

So when I go to http://example.com/site1/index.html it takes me to http://example.com/index.html. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have pasted the relevant portions of the nginx.conf and and example express route below.

nginx.conf

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name 11.11.11.111;
            root /home/ubuntu;

            location /site1/ {
                    proxy_pass http://11.11.11.111:8000/;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_pass http://11.11.11.111:8000/;
                    proxy_redirect http://11.11.11.111/* http://11.11.11.111:8000/*;
            }
            location /site2/ {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_pass http://11.11.11.111:8001/;
                    proxy_redirect http://11.11.11.111/* http://11.11.11.111:8001/*;
            }
}
```

app.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/index.html');
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472345/node-nginx-proxy-on-multiple-ports-same-domain-not-working/59597413#59597413

Answer (score 0):

In my admittedly limited experience with **nginx** and **proxy_pass**, I have found that nginx doesn't truly hand off the request to the proxied application when you use **proxy_pass**.  Any request to the exact **location** block path with the exact **server_name** specified in the server block will be handed off correctly, i.e.:

```
http://11.11.11.11/site1/
http://11.11.11.11/site1/index.html
```

but the following requests will fail:

```
http://11.11.11.11/site1
http://example.com/site1
http://example.com/site1/
http://example.com/site1/index.html
```

because they don't match the **location** block path exactly.  Also, any sub-directory under that path will get served by nginx unless told otherwise.  For example:

```
http://11.11.11.11/site1/ <-- Succeeds
http://11.11.11.11/site1/js <-- Fails
```

You have to be explicit with nginx.  You need to specify the **root** path where your applications live on your server, use regex-like **location** path specifications, and use **rewrite** so nginx knows not to deal with anything after your proxied path:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myserver;
    root /var/html/node; # The parent directory of where your apps live

    location ^~ /app1/ {
        rewrite ^/app1(.*) /real/app1/path$1;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect https://myserver/app1 /real/app1/path;
    }

    location ^~ /app2/ {
        rewrite ^/app2(.*) /real/app2/path$1;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_redirect https://myserver/app2 /real/app2/path;
    }
}
```

**/real/app[x]/path** should be a real directory under **/var/html/node** and should be accessible by the user running nginx.  Your config may need some tweaking to work, but this should get you most of the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the **nginx.conf** file. Before saving, close any active instances running for nginx from control panel.

```
http {
upstream backend{
    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
    server 127.0.0.1:2001;
    server 127.0.0.1:2002;
    server 127.0.0.1:2003;
    server 127.0.0.1:2004;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    root   "E:\testing";
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }}}
 events {}
```