# node nginx proxy on multiple ports, same domain not working

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have setup reverse proxy for ngnix for the node app running 8042 and I want to do the same for admin app running on 8043 and it is simply not working, Couldn't find the issue.

This works,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {
       rewrite ^/proj(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8042;


   }

}
```

This doesn't, both code exists on same sites-available/default file

```
server {
        listen 8881 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location /proj-admin {
           rewrite ^/proj-admin(.*) /$1 break;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8043;

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your current nginx.conf file in the /etc/nginx folder with the following,

```
#worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
   sendfile on;

   gzip on;
   gzip_disable "msie6";

   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_comp_level 6;
   gzip_buffers 16 8k;
   gzip_http_version 1.1;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    log_format timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log timed_combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    upstream api_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:8042;
    }

    upstream admin_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:8043;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 404;
    }

   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
           proxy_pass         http://api_server;
           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_set_header   Host $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }


        location /proj-admin {
           proxy_pass         http://admin_server;
           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_set_header   Host $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that one work with me

```
...

location /api/ {
            rewrite /api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
...
```